# What's the correct query String to query google via a webview

Tags: android

I'm not looking for an intent as these trigger a browsing session. Instead, I'm trying to have a webview inside my app that refreshes to a google search.

I've tried www.google.com/search?q=test and that unfortunately sends me to the results via some annoying redirect page first. I've tried www.google.com/ncr?q=test and this just sends me to a google page with a blank search box (won't prefill the search).

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question after much playing around, it appears that the cleanest way (ie. the least chance of redirect from google servers) is to use www.google.com/m?q=test

I hope this helps!

Comment: A belated 'thank you' for this answer!!! This helped me a great deal to customize my search engines in `Conkeror` and `w3m`.